# ajax called in Laravel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

i want move values with ajax called :

```
 $.ajax({
             url: '/index.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
               lat: position.lat(),
               lng: position.lng()
             },
             success: function(response) {
            alert("OK");   
             }
           });
```

But it can't find the file with this path. I use Laravel in /var/www/laravel/resources/views/map/index .
I tried to enter the full path, but it doesn't work too. 
What I 'm wrong ?

Comment: can you share your routes that where you are pointing your ajax request. also share your Ajax console screen shot, so we can the response/error

Answer (score 0):

With laravel this won't work. You need to add a route in your routes.php file.

```
Route::post('/test', TestController@test);
```

In your ajax just change the url from

```
/index.php
```

To

```
/test
```

Comment: If this helped you should consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example:** This code will also work for you ...  ***Headers*** are important when we make ***post*** request. ***Get*** request doesn't require any headers. I think this will also help you to understand about headers.....

**HTML:**

```
<html>
       <head>
          <title>Ajax Example</title>
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var csrf_token   =   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token}
            });
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id='msg'>
             Click the button to replace the message.</div>
          <button onclick = "getMessage()">Replace Message</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
  function getMessage(){
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'getmsg',
       dataType:'json', 
       success:function(data){
        $("#msg").html(data.msg);
       },
       error:function(){
        alert('loading error...')
       }
    });
 }
</script>
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('ajax',function(){
   return view('message');
});
Route::post('getmsg','AjaxController@index');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
   public function index(){
      $msg = "This is a simple message.";
      return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
}
```